# Regex matching only once

Tags: c#, regex

I have text

```
1
00:00:03,837 --> 00:00:07,170
Text1

2
00:00:08,875 --> 00:00:10,968
Tex2

3
00:00:11,010 --> 00:00:13,843
Text3
```

And I want to make it like that

```
00:00:03,837 --> 00:00:07,170
Text1

00:00:08,875 --> 00:00:10,968
Tex2

00:00:11,010 --> 00:00:13,843
Text3
```

I tried this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(loadedText, @"\d{1,4}\r\n");

if (match.Success)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
    {
        loadedText= loadedText.Replace(match.Groups[i].Value, "");
    }
    rtbLoaded.Text = loadedText;
}
```

Bu it give me this result:

```
00:00:03,837 --> 00:00:07,170
Text1

2
00:00:08,875 --> 00:00:10,968
Tex2

3
00:00:11,010 --> 00:00:13,843
Text3
```

So it much only once... What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this replace rule:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(originalString, @"(?<=(\r\n|^))(\d+\r\n)", "");
```

This will replace all lines with only numbers or a line with a number in the first line.

Refering to your example input:

```
string input = "1\r\n00:00:03,837 --> 00:00:07,170\r\nText1\r\n\r\n2\r\n00:00:08,875 --> 00:00:10,968\r\nTex2\r\n\r\n3\r\n00:00:11,010 --> 00:00:13,843\r\nText3\r\n\r\n";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=(\r\n|^))(\d+\r\n)", ""));
```

This outputs:

> 00:00:03,837 --> 00:00:07,170
>   Text1
>
> 00:00:08,875 --> 00:00:10,968
>   Tex2
>
> 00:00:11,010 --> 00:00:13,843
>   Text3

Answer (score 1):

Groups are the parts in  `()` in a regexp, not the individual matches.

So in the regexp `(abc)(def)` the first group is `abc`, the second group is `def`.

Don't iterate over the *groups* (you only have the default group!), you need to *match* multiple times. Maybe use a built in replacement method instead of this `Replace` hack that you are doing there.